# Inconsistent Date format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am new to Python, I have a file having date column as below formats:

```
date = pd.Series(['10-21-2012 ', '7-18-2019 ', '02-2-2008', 
                  '2010/21/4 ', '11-8-2019 '])
```

I used the following code to get the month but I get an error:

> ValueError: month must be in 1..12

Code:

```
pd.to_datetime(date).dt.month
```

The output should be

```
10
7
02
4
11
```

Please can someone help me with this?

Comment: The date values are not consistent. Some have `/`

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62233084/how-can-i-clean-date-ranges-in-multiple-formats-using-python-pandas/62233880#62233880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome!
You could "normalize" the date list before passing it the Pandas Series object.
Create a function that can do it and you could also use it somewhere else in your code should you require it.
From your series it seems like you have two main formats that the dates are arranged by:
- **mm-dd-yyyy**
- **yyyy/dd/mm**

```
def get_months(date_list):  
    month_list = []  
    m = ''
    for dt_string in date_list:
        if "-" in dt_string:
            numbers = [int(x) for x in dt_string.split("-")]
            m = f'{numbers[0]}-{numbers[1]}-{numbers[2]}'
            month_list.append(m)
        elif "/" in dt_string:
            numbers = [int(x) for x in dt_string.split("/")]
            m = f'{numbers[2]}-{numbers[1]}-{numbers[0]}'
            month_list.append(m)
    return month_list

dates = ['10-21-2012', '7-18-2019', '02-2-2008', '2010/21/4', '11-8-2019']

months = get_months(dates)

[print(x) for x in months]
```

This would create a list that look like:

```
['10-21-2012','7-18-2019','2-2-2008','4-21-2010','11-8-2019']
```

Let me know if you have special requirements that would not make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the values that have `/`

```
In [13]: date = pd.Series(['10-21-2012 ', '7-18-2019 ', '02-2-2008',
    ...:                 '2010/21/4 ', '11-8-2019 '])

In [14]: pd.to_datetime(date, errors="coerce").dt.month
Out[14]:
0    10.0
1     7.0
2     2.0
3     NaN
4    11.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: : I already did this, but ignoring values that have '/' will lead to significant loss of data in my dataset.

Comment: You could follow the accepted answer and apply this answer